# scrollbar is not visible in android phone gap?

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to phone gap.i have display list of data in list view. The data collect from server and i want add scroll bar to the view . How add scroll bar in phone gap and my view Scrolling is sticky. how to make it smooth .

I have added iscroll into my html file and i have used following code,

```
<script language = "javascript" src = "../scripts/iscroll.js"></script>
```

my html doby code is,

```
<body onLoad="initList()">

    <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="scroller">
     </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

my java script code is,

```
function initList()
{

    var statsIds    = [];
    var array       = ["Active", "Paused"];
    $.ajax(
        {
          url       : campaignStatus,
          success   : function(data) 
          {
            var data        = JSON.parse(data);
            var count       = data.content.count;
            var res         = data.content.response;

            $.each(res, function(k, v)
            {
                statsArray.push(v.status);
                statsIds[v.status]  = v.id;
            });
          }
        });

    $.ajax(
        {
            url     : campaignlistURL,
            success : function(data) 
            {
                var data        = JSON.parse(data);
                var count       = data.content.count;
                response        = data.content.response;

                var page = '<div id="top-box"><div id="lable-box"><div class="lable-txt">Campaign List</div></div><div id="search-box"><div class="search"><div class="left"><img src="../images/search-img.png"></div><div class="middle"><input type="text" id="search" placeholder="search by Campaign Name.." onkeyup="campaignsSearch()"/></div></div></div></div>';

                page    += '<div id="empty-container"></div>';

                page    += '<div id="table-container">';                                    
                //----------------------------------
                $.each(response, function(k, v)
                {

                    page    += '<div class="table-box">';
                    page    += '<div class="top">';             
                    page    += '<div class="left"><label>Campaign Name:</label><input type="text" class="campaign" readonly="true" value='+v.name+' onClick="openCampaignDetails()" id='+v.id+'></div>';

                    var statusId    = v.status;
                    var count       = 0;
                    page    += '<div class="right"><label>Status</label>';
                    for(var i=0; i<statsArray.length; i++)
                    {
                        if(statusId == i)
                        {
                            if(statsArray[i] == "Active" || statsArray[i] == "Paused")
                            {
                                if(count == 0)
                                {
                                    page += '<select id="'+v.id+'" onchange="statusChange()">';
                                }

                                for(var j=0; j<array.length; j++)
                                {
                                    //console.log(statsIds[array[j]] + array[j]);

                                    if(array[j] == statsArray[i])
                                    {
                                        page += '<option id='+statsIds[array[j]]+' SELECTED>'+array[j]+'</option>';
                                    }

                                    else
                                    {
                                        page += '<option id='+statsIds[array[j]]+'>'+array[j]+'</option>';
                                    }

                                }
                                count++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                page += statsArray[i];
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    page    += '</select>';
                    page    += '</div>';
                    page    +='</div>'; //-- top -

                    //*******Table***********
                    var statistics  = v.stats;
                    if(statistics)
                    {
                        page    += '<div class="table-data"><div class="column"><div class="header">IMPS </div><div class="middle">'+statistics.sum.adjusted_views+'</div></div><div class="column"><div class="header">Clicks </div><div class="middle">'+statistics.sum.adjusted_clicks+'</div></div><div class="column"><div class="header"> Costs </div><div class="middle">'+statistics.sum.adjusted_cost+' </div></div><div class="column" style="border:0px;"><div class="header"> Leads</div><div class="middle">'+statistics.sum.adjusted_convs_0+'</div></div></div>';
                    }                   
                    page    += '</div>'; //-- table-box

                });
                page    += '</div>'; //-- table-container -

                page    += '<div id="footer"><div class="left-logo"><img src="../images/logo-2.png" width="111" height="39" onClick="reloadCampaigns()"></div><div class="right-log-out"><a href="#"><img src="../images/log-out.png" width="21" height="18" border="0" onClick="logout()"></a></div></div>';
                document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = page;
                document.getElementById("table-container").style.overflow="scroll";

                var myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper',{fixedScrollbar : false,hideScrollbar:false});
                //document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);

              //    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { setTimeout(loaded, 200); }, false);
                //------------------
            }
        });
}
```

I think i have done some mistake Please guide me to do this.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Why do you need to 'show' a scrollbar? I believe the way it's handled on phonegap is that a location indication will show up when the user starts to scroll to give an indication of where they are in respect to the amount of content in the view. The user can scroll with their finger with or without the scroll bar showing, assuming the view itself is scrollable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the [nicescroller](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/)

it's nice, smooth, easy to implement and best of all, it support touch.
as simple as:

```
var nice = false;
$(document).ready(
  function() { 
    nice = $("#div").niceScroll();
   }
);
```

Just make sure that your data have fix height, if the height is changing upon reading the data from the server you may re-initialise the nicescroll each time the height changes.

```
$("#div").getNicescroll().remove().niceScroll();
```

Comment: The developer suggests to call `$('#div').getNiceScroll().resize();` upon ajax actions to adapt it to the new content height.

Comment: yeah, it was fixed after i posted my answer 2 years ago, now niceScroll is not much much better  @Andrew